# Calling query inside query in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, linq, memory-leaks, linq-method-syntax

I want to do something like this

```cs
public string GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory(int siteId)
{
    var changeHistories = changeHistoryRepository.GetAll(c => c.SiteRegistryId == siteId);
    var value = changeHistories.firstOrDefault(r=>r.State="Active")
    return value.Title;
}

public IQueryable<PendingReconfirmation> GetSitesForBusinessReconfirmationReminder(IList<StateStatus> stateStatusMappingIds,
    string country, int reminderDay)
{
    
    return from reg in repositorySpositeRegistry.GetAll(x => x.SiteUrlcountryCode != null
            && x.SiteUrlcountryCode.ToLower() == country.ToLower())
            
            select new PendingReconfirmation()
            {
                Id = reg.Id,
                SiteTitle = GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory(reg.Id!).ToString() ?? reg.SiteTitle,
                
            };
}
```

Repository.GetAll look like this

```cs
public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter = null)
{
    var query = entities.AsQueryable();
    if (filter != null)
        query = query.Where(filter);
    return query;
}
```

But I am getting error

> The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of '' through the instance method 'GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance.

But I cant make the method as static .
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you ready to use third party extensions like LINQKit?

Comment: Did you "consider" what the exception says?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No

Comment: @GertArnold  Static will not work for me

Comment: Then you have to repeat `LINQKit` functionality. Expression should be corrected before passing to EF translator. There is no other option.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: you could use  `Join` instead. I see it's doable in your query since site registry are sharing `SiteId`.

Answer (score 0):

Make this function GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory as STATIC.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you split up GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory into a separate method?

Otherwise you should be able to do a subquery like so, provided the queryable used for the subquery is based on a dbset in the same efcontext:

```
public IQueryable<PendingReconfirmation> GetSitesForBusinessReconfirmationReminder(IList<StateStatus> stateStatusMappingIds,
                                                                                   string             country, int reminderDay)
{
    return from reg in repositorySpositeRegistry.GetAll(x => x.SiteUrlcountryCode != null
                                                             && x.SiteUrlcountryCode.ToLower() == country.ToLower())
            
           select new PendingReconfirmation()
           {
               Id        = reg.Id,
               SiteTitle = changeHistoryRepository.GetAll(c => c.SiteRegistryId == reg.Id && c.State == "Active").FirstOrDefault().Title ?? reg.Title
           };
}
```

Comment: I have a reason to do that. I am calling GetSiteTitleFromChangeHistory in many places